# swift - add tableview pagination of posts from reddit API

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination, reddit

I'm getting data from Reddit API and displaying reddit posts in the tableview. I want to load 5 (for example) posts from api at a time and display them, and then load next 5 posts when the user scroll down to the last fifth cell.
Maybe I need to change my logic of getting posts from api. Please advice. Thank you!

I'm using MVVM. Populate tableview cells with posts data in TableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell") as! PostTableViewCell
        
        vm.getPost(at: indexPath.row) { post in
            guard let post = post else { print("No post"); return }
            print(post)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.usernameLabel.text = post.username
                cell.domainLabel.text = post.domain
                cell.titleLabel.text = post.title
                cell.detailsLabel.text = post.text
                
                cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(post.imageURL)"))
                
                cell.timePassedLabel.text = post.createdHoursAgo
                
                cell.ratingButton.setTitle("\(post.rating)", for: .normal)
                cell.commentsButton.setTitle("\(post.comments)", for: .normal)
            }
            
            // pagination
        }
     return cell
}
```

Get one post:

```
class PostViewModel {
    
    var limit = 30
    let sub = "ios"
    
    var portion = 5
    
    var post: RedditPost?
    
    func getPost(at postIndex: Int, completion: (@escaping (_ data: RedditPost?) -> Void)) {
        
        UseCase().createPosts(sub: sub, limit: limit) { posts in
            
            // there are not so many posts on reddit as you asked for (as limit)
            if self.limit > posts.count {
                print("Error: Number of demanded posts are bigger than available on Reddit")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                let post = posts[postIndex]
                self.post = post
                completion(post)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Get all posts from API:

```
class UseCase {
    
    func createPosts(sub: String, limit: Int, completion: (@escaping (_ data: [RedditPost]) -> Void)) {
        
        Repository().fillPostsArray(sub: sub, limit: limit) { (redditPosts: [RedditPost]) in
            completion(redditPosts)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the first API call should be made from the `viewDidLoad` method and `reload` the `tableView` when the response comes.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupTableView()
    loadPostsFromRedit()
}

private func loadPostsFromRedit() {
   vm.getPost(at: indexPath.row) { [weak self] posts in
        guard let self = self, let post = posts else { 
          return 
        }
        print(posts)
        self.post = posts
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}
```

Pagination:

You can use the `willDisplayCell` method to check if the user has reached the end of the `tableView` and call the API to load the next page

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if post.count == indexPath.row - 1 {
            vm.loadMorePosts()
        }
    }
```

Note: you also need to pass the page index to redit API to return the correct page response. Refer this tutorial for more details https://www.raywenderlich.com/5786-uitableview-infinite-scrolling-tutorial